# Iterate over classes in jar file

Tags: java

Anyone knows a 2-3 line solution for iterating over classes in some Jar file ?

( I have an instance of java.net.URL in my hand )

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[Accessing zips and jars using Java Part 1](http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/607681/Accessing-zips-and-jars-using-Java-Part-1)

[Accessing zips and jars using Java Part 2](http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/607931/Accessing-zips-and-jars-using-Java-Part-2)

Here is a code snippet from first article:

```
  ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(fileName);

  // Process the zip file. Close it when the block is exited.

  try {
     // Loop through the zip entries and print the name of each one.

     for (Enumeration list = zip.entries(); list.hasMoreElements(); ) {
        ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) list.nextElement();
        System.out.println(entry.getName());
     }
  }
  finally {
     zip.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

jar -tf xyz.jar|grep class

[Here's a solution](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0513.html). You can create an input stream from the URL instead of the file that the code uses.