# How to warm up java classes to avoid slow first call?

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-boot

I am doing a project where I need all the API calls to take less than 1s but I am facing an issue with the first call to each route that is slower than the following ones.

Currently the first call to /login takes 3.6s and the next ones take 170ms and same for all the other routes.

I found out using `-XX:+TraceClassLoading` that on the first call, the classes were loaded in memory and that caused the performance issue.

However I did not find an easy way of loading all the classes at start up and for each new service, I need to add a warm up call in an ApplicationRunner.

Does anyone have a solution to automatically load the classes of a SpringBoot application or warm up all its routes?

Comment: Can you add more details? Is your application instantiating controlers? Or are you calling other services? How are you making the calls to other services?

Comment: Spring Boot uses class scanning intensively, so you don't need to 'warm up' anything like on desktop application. This long initial load could be result of resource searching  - for example page template loading.

Comment: A bit of an indirect approach: if you have 100% unit test coverage for the endpoints you could use them. You would still have to code per endpoint but you gain something

Comment: Might not be ideal depending on the project you are doing, but you could call your endpoints internally when your application is loaded.

Comment: @omoshiroiii there's _nothing_ wrong with that. we do it. in production. the reason has to do with some dynamic libraries that use `invokedynamic` and we _know_ the resolution is slow on the first call for those (we have tens of thousands of such calls, which without this first call accumulate to tens of seconds).

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos Yes I use RestController with my own Service that I autowire.

Comment: @Eugene I am currently using this approach but it is painful. First I need to create a new warm up call for each new endpoint and I have some endpoints that require specific authentication.
Do you have a solution to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Java's class loading is lazy. This means a class is only loaded by the JVM when it needs to and if it needs to.

If you want to force it to eagerly load classes you just need to reference them. One way of doing it is to iterate through the jar contents or class files to get the class names and then use them to call `Class.forName(className)`.

Additionally, if startup time and performance is very important for your use case, you might want to look into ahead of time compilation solutions like [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/native-image/), or reduce JIT's threshold for compilation (`-XX:CompileThreshold`).

Comment: neither of those will solve OP's problem. loading is still lazy in GraalVM and `JIT` is meaningless on the _first_ invocations, really.

Comment: also, `GraalVM` is good, but please have a look at the number of issues it has in github: as soon as you go from a sandbox project to something bigger (I am looking at you reflection, mainly), you will be in some pain, at least. my point is : swapping to GraalVM is not a simple snap of fingers.

Comment: I thought about loading the classes in the jar but I didn't find a way of doing it, would you have an example?

Comment: @Eugene if you read my answer you will see that I haven't said GraalVM or the JIT threshold would change the lazyness of class loading. The answer to OP's question regarding lazyness is the paragraph before that one. The last paragraph is just an additional tip in case OP needs to further optimize startup time/performance beyond class loading.

Comment: @Ybri there are other questions with answers to that here, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370867/iterate-over-classes-in-jar-file

Comment: @andresp the point is OP cares about _first_ invocation, _specifically_ because of class loading, so the argument to use GraalVM and tweak JIT is just noise, and the argument is mute, as such.

Comment: It might be noise to you, but you don't talk for everyone, so you argument is mute too.

Comment: @andresp :) this is called "howaboutism", as such when this happens, I stop commenting.

Comment: @andresp I did not find any article about how to load all the classes in an application that is a started as a war. Would you have any example on how to do that?

Comment: Both jar and war files are just zip compressed files. You should be able to iterate over its contents the same way. You will just have to take in consideration their specific directory structure and the possibility of having more jars inside WEB-INF/lib. Alternatively if your container explodes the war, you can look at the exploded directory instead.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the only viable option you have is `class data sharing`, spread across [JEP 310](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/310), [JEP 341](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/341) and [JEP 350](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/350), but this requires java-13 most probably. We are testing this internally at my work place (mostly for fun, not going to lie) and the results look good, so far.

The other option is calling your endpoints when the application starts - if that is an option. Again, it *is* for us for example: we call them with dummy data a couple of hundreds of times to warm up the code. But, at the same time, we have services where this would be impossible - that's why the exploring of `CDS` too.

Comment: How do you handle the authentication and the post endpoints to avoid the creation of data in your production database?

Comment: @Ybri exactly why I said, _impossible_ for some.